# Umask not working for error logs

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have the umask set up on my Apache2 server as `002`. This is added to the end of `/etc/apache2/envvars` during the docker container build.

I have the following script to test:

```
// Create file
if ($fp = fopen(time() . '.txt', 'w')) {
    fwrite($fp, 'This is a simple test.');
    fclose($fp);
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "error - cannot create file";
}

// Generate error
error_log("This be an error", 0);
```

This creates 2 files: `error_log_dev` (as set in my php.ini) and `1520215096.txt`. The permissions for each of these files are as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   22 Mar  5 11:58 1520215096.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   55 Mar  5 11:58 error_log_dev
```

Why would the error log not be abiding by the umask but `fopen()` does?

Comment: I solved something similar by adding a chmod command in my startup script.

Comment: @Nic3500 can you elaborate more on that please? Start up script for what? And what did you change the permissions of?

Comment: You say your permissions on error_log_dev are not what you want.  So in `apachectl`, at the end, I added a `chmod` command to put 664 (or put whatever you need).  Only downside, if you upgrade and your `apachectl` changes, you will have to put back that customization.